# Access element of MATLAB multi-dimensional array specified by another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a MATLAB function which returns a 4-element vector, e.g. `[1 2 3 4]`. I would like to use that function output to access the corresponding element in an existing 4-dimensional vector, i.e. `vec(1, 2, 3, 4)`. Is there a way to do this *without* storing the result and then explicitly accessing the elements, as in the following?

```
result = f(blah);
myElement = vec(result(1), result(2), result(3), result(4));
```

In my (Python-influenced) head, the answer looks something like this:

```
result = f(blah);
myElement = vec(*result); % or vec(toSubscripts(result)); or similar
```

The `*` operator in Python expands a list into comma-separated arguments. Is there an analogous operator or function in MATLAB that will help solve my problem?

Comment: What result function will return?

Comment: @Jonas, I'm not sure that question will help me. The duplicate I just noticed and commented above is more helpful.

Comment: @Sam: indeed you had found a much better match. That's why I used the link you provided to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something like `*result` in matlab, it's called comma separated list. Unfortunately you can not create a comma separated list from a array, thus conversion to a cell is first required:

```
result=(num2cell(f(blah)));
myElement=v(result{:});
```